# Moving from Gitolite to Gerrit

Tags: git, gitolite, gerrit, gitweb

I have been using gitolite from the past few months and have been very satisfied with the combo. but now i am looking at moving towards a better managed web front-end where i can do the code review together.

I found Gerrit is the best tool for my requirement but i wonder how do i move and manage all the users/projects from gitolite to gerrit. I already did the gitweb integration with gerrit that gives me nice web interface but having issues with migration.

Does anyone have experience with this method?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Well, how many do you have? Manually: create bare repos in gerrit and push branches to each of them from the same local repo as the ones you use for your gitolite projects (i.e. `git remote add <gerritalias> <gerrit-url>` for each of your repos then push to them)

Comment: Michas- actually i am trying to configure the gitolite Projects and users in to gerrit. Thanks Sebastien but we have 1000+ repos in the git server and its a bit hassel to push each repos manually to gerrit. is there any better way you know?

Comment: also i am worried about user configuration on gerrit from gitolite. How do i move the users from gitolite to gerrit who has same access (R/W) to the respective repos.